# How to make a rubber band in my PyQt5 paint application?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qrubberband

I've made a simple paint application which can open and save files, draw on pictures with different brush colors and brush sizes, but i don't know how to properly use QRubberBand, so I'm stuck with a blue square appearing on the screen (at the cursor pos). It doesn't do anything with the things I draw, so I'm quite confused. Thanks in advance.

file "graphic.py", the application

```
# graphic.py
#  Импортирую библиотеки
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import sys
import io
#  Импортирую класс с дизайном
from graphic_ui import Ui_GRedWindow


class GRedactor(QMainWindow, Ui_GRedWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(GRedactor, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        #  Создаю холст
        self.image = QImage(QSize(800, 600), QImage.Format_RGB32)
        #  Меняю при необходимости
        self.filePath = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Выберите картинку', '',
                                                    'jpg (*.jpg);;jpeg (*.jpeg);;png (*.png);;все файлы (*)')[0]
        self.create_new_canvas(self.filePath)
        #  Заполняю холст белым цветом
        #  Создаю флаг для рисования, устанавливаю дефолтные размер и цвет кисти
        self.drawing = False
        self.brushType = 'Кисть'
        self.rubberBand = QRubberBand(QRubberBand.Rectangle, self)
        self.brushSize = 4
        self.brushColor = Qt.black
        #  Создаю переменную QPoint для отслеживания курсора
        self.position = QPoint()
        #  Создаю действия QAction
        clearAction = self.action
        clearAction.triggered.connect(self.clear)
        openAction = self.action_2
        openAction.triggered.connect(self.open)
        saveAction = self.action_3
        saveAction.triggered.connect(self.save)
        saveAsAction = self.action_4
        saveAsAction.triggered.connect(self.save_as)
        brushAction = self.action_5
        brushAction.triggered.connect(self.brush)
        rubberAction = self.action_6
        rubberAction.triggered.connect(self.rubber)
        pix4 = self.action4px
        pix4.triggered.connect(self.pix4)
        pix6 = self.action6px
        pix6.triggered.connect(self.pix6)
        pix8 = self.action8px
        pix8.triggered.connect(self.pix8)
        pix10 = self.action10px
        pix10.triggered.connect(self.pix10)
        pix12 = self.action12px
        pix12.triggered.connect(self.pix12)
        white = self.action_7
        white.triggered.connect(self.white)
        gray = self.action_8
        gray.triggered.connect(self.gray)
        black = self.action_9
        black.triggered.connect(self.black)
        red = self.action_10
        red.triggered.connect(self.red)
        orange = self.action_11
        orange.triggered.connect(self.orange)
        yellow = self.action_12
        yellow.triggered.connect(self.yellow)
        green = self.action_13
        green.triggered.connect(self.green)
        blue = self.action_14
        blue.triggered.connect(self.blue)
        dark_blue = self.action_15
        dark_blue.triggered.connect(self.dark_blue)
        purple = self.action_16
        purple.triggered.connect(self.purple)
        your_color = self.action_17
        your_color.triggered.connect(self.your_color)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        #  По нажатию мыши начинаю рисовать
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.drawing = True
            #  Сохраняю позицию курсора
            self.position = event.pos()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        #  Рисую по движению мыши
        if (event.buttons() & Qt.LeftButton) & self.drawing:
            if self.brushType == 'Кисть':
                canvas_qp = QPainter(self.image)
                canvas_qp.setPen(QPen(self.brushColor, self.brushSize, Qt.SolidLine, Qt.RoundCap, Qt.RoundJoin))
                canvas_qp.drawLine(self.position, event.pos())
                self.position = event.pos()
                self.update()
            elif self.brushType == 'Ластик':
                self.rubberBand.setGeometry(QRect(event.pos(), QSize(self.brushSize, self.brushSize)))
                self.rubberBand.show()
                self.position = event.pos()
                self.update()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            #  Больше не рисую
            self.drawing = False
            self.rubberBand.hide()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        #  Создаю qp для холста
        qp = QPainter(self)
        #  Рисую "точку"
        qp.drawImage(self.rect(), self.image, self.image.rect())

    def save(self):
        self.image.save(self.filePath)

    #  Сохранить как
    def save_as(self):
        self.filePath, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, "Сохранить картинку", "",
                                                       "PNG(*.png);;JPEG(*.jpg *.jpeg);;Все файлы(*.*)")
        if not self.filePath:
            return

        self.image.save(self.filePath)

    #  Очистить / Создать новый холст
    def clear(self):
        self.image.fill(Qt.white)
        self.update()

    #  Открыть
    def open(self):
        self.filePath, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Открыть картинку", "",
                                                       "PNG(*.png);;JPEG(*.jpg *.jpeg);;Все файлы(*.*)")
        self.create_new_canvas(self.filePath)

    def pix4(self):
        self.brushSize = 4

    def pix6(self):
        self.brushSize = 6

    def pix8(self):
        self.brushSize = 8

    def pix10(self):
        self.brushSize = 10

    def pix12(self):
        self.brushSize = 12

    def white(self):
        self.brushColor = Qt.white

    def gray(self):
        self.brushColor = Qt.gray

    def black(self):
        self.brushColor = Qt.black

    def red(self):
        self.brushColor = Qt.red

    def orange(self):
        self.brushColor = QColor(255, 140, 0)

    def yellow(self):
        self.brushColor = Qt.yellow

    def green(self):
        self.brushColor = Qt.green

    def blue(self):
        self.brushColor = QColor(0, 190, 255)

    def dark_blue(self):
        self.brushColor = Qt.darkBlue

    #  Фиолетовый цвет
    def purple(self):
        self.brushColor = Qt.darkMagenta

    #  Свой цвет
    def your_color(self):
        self.brushColor = QColorDialog.getColor()

    def create_new_canvas(self, filepath):
        #  Не выбран файл - пустой холст
        if filepath == '':
            self.image = QImage(800, 600, QImage.Format_RGB32)
            self.image.fill(Qt.white)
            self.resize(800, 600)
        else:
            #  Cоздаю QImage() файла и увеличиваю его при необходимости
            self.image = QImage(filepath)
            if self.image.width() < 300 or self.image.height() < 300:
                self.image = self.image.scaled(300, 300, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
            self.resize(self.image.width(), self.image.height())
        self.update()

    def brush(self):
        self.brushType = 'Кисть'

    def rubber(self):
        self.brushType = 'Ластик'


def except_hook(cls, exception, traceback):
    sys.__excepthook__(cls, exception, traceback)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = GRedactor()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

file "graphic_ui.py", ui of the application

```
# graphic_ui.py

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'untitled.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.9
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_GRedWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menu.setObjectName("menu")
        self.menu_3 = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menu_3.setObjectName("menu_3")
        self.menu_4 = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menu_4.setObjectName("menu_4")
        self.menu_2 = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menu_2.setObjectName("menu_2")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.action = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action.setObjectName("action")
        self.action_2 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action_2.setObjectName("action_2")
        self.action_3 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action_3.setObjectName("action_3")
        self.action_4 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action_4.setObjectName("action_4")
        self.action_5 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action_5.setObjectName("action_5")
        self.action_6 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action_6.setObjectName("action_6")
        self.action_7 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action_7.setObjectName("action_7")
        self.action_8 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action_8.setObjectName("action_8")
        self.action_9 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action_9.setObjectName("action_9")
        self.action_10 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action_10.setObjectName("action_10")
        self.action_11 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action_11.setObjectName("action_11")
        self.action_12 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action_12.setObjectName("action_12")
        self.action_13 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action_13.setObjectName("action_13")
        self.action_14 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action_14.setObjectName("action_14")
        self.action_15 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action_15.setObjectName("action_15")
        self.action_16 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action_16.setObjectName("action_16")
        self.action_17 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action_17.setObjectName("action_17")
        self.action4px = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action4px.setObjectName("action4px")
        self.action6px = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action6px.setObjectName("action6px")
        self.action8px = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action8px.setObjectName("action8px")
        self.action10px = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action10px.setObjectName("action10px")
        self.action12px = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action12px.setObjectName("action12px")
        self.menu.addAction(self.action)
        self.menu.addAction(self.action_2)
        self.menu.addAction(self.action_3)
        self.menu.addAction(self.action_4)
        self.menu_3.addAction(self.action_7)
        self.menu_3.addAction(self.action_8)
        self.menu_3.addAction(self.action_9)
        self.menu_3.addAction(self.action_10)
        self.menu_3.addAction(self.action_11)
        self.menu_3.addAction(self.action_12)
        self.menu_3.addAction(self.action_13)
        self.menu_3.addAction(self.action_14)
        self.menu_3.addAction(self.action_15)
        self.menu_3.addAction(self.action_16)
        self.menu_3.addAction(self.action_17)
        self.menu_4.addAction(self.action4px)
        self.menu_4.addAction(self.action6px)
        self.menu_4.addAction(self.action8px)
        self.menu_4.addAction(self.action10px)
        self.menu_4.addAction(self.action12px)
        self.menu_2.addAction(self.action_5)
        self.menu_2.addAction(self.action_6)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menu.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menu_2.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menu_3.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menu_4.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.menu.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Файл"))
        self.menu_3.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Цвет"))
        self.menu_4.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Размер"))
        self.menu_2.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Кисть"))
        self.action.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Создать"))
        self.action_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Открыть"))
        self.action_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Сохранить"))
        self.action_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Сохранить как"))
        self.action_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Обычная (круглая)"))
        self.action_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ластик"))
        self.action_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Белый"))
        self.action_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Серый"))
        self.action_9.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Чёрный"))
        self.action_10.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Красный"))
        self.action_11.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Оранжевый"))
        self.action_12.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Жёлтый"))
        self.action_13.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Зелёный"))
        self.action_14.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Голубой"))
        self.action_15.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Синий"))
        self.action_16.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Фиолетовый"))
        self.action_17.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выбрать свой"))
        self.action4px.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "4px"))
        self.action6px.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "6px"))
        self.action8px.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "8px"))
        self.action10px.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "10px"))
        self.action12px.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "12px"))
```

I hope there are no issues with the language

Comment: You should set the origin point of the rubberband on mouse press and then change its size based on the mouse position on movement. Instead, you're always repositioning the rubber band and keeping the default size. Note that, for such purposes, you should never paint on the main window, but on an actual "canvas widget", which will directly handle mouse movements for painting or anything related to it (including selection). You should also consider using the [Graphics View framework](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html).